# ejecucion entra al while aunque no debe hacerlo C

Tags: c

estoy haciendo un codigo que calcula el promedio de numeros ingresados mediante el teclado hasta que das el valor 9999. Lo que pasa con mi programa es que aunque el programa termina cuando metes el valor, la suma tambien cuenta al numero 9999, y no deberia de hacerlo.
Agradezco cualquier sugerencia :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int suma=0;
    int numero;
    int contador=0;
    double promedio;
    
    printf("Introduce el numero que formara parte del promedio\n");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    suma = suma + numero;
    while (numero!=9999) {
        printf("Introduce el siguiente numero que formara parte del promedio\n");
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        suma = suma + numero;
        contador++;
    }
    printf("el contador vale: %d\n", contador);
    printf("%d\n", suma);
    promedio = suma / contador;
    printf("el promedio de los numeros ingresados es: %.2f\n", promedio);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que estas haciendo la lectura de tu numero antes de la suma, entonces cuando ingresas el 9999 ya estas dentro de tu bucle y tu proximo paso es sumarlo a tu acumulador.

Te propongo una solución:

```
    int suma=0;
    int numero=0;
    int contador=0;
    double promedio;
    printf("Introduce el siguiente numero que formara parte del promedio\n");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    while (numero != 9999) {
        suma = suma + numero;
        contador++;
        printf("Introduce el siguiente numero que formara parte del promedio\n");
        scanf("%d", &numero);
    }
    printf("el contador vale: %d\n", contador);
    printf("%d\n", suma);
    promedio = suma / contador;
    printf("el promedio de los numeros ingresados es: %.2f\n", promedio);
    return 0;
```

Es una estrategia que uso mucho, se llama lectura adelantada, vuelves a leer al final de tu bucle para evitar volver  a  comparar por la misma condicion.

Comment: tienes toda la razón, gracias :)